# sudo persistent across ssh logins

Tags: ssh, sudo

When I have two separate terminals logged in via SSH to my server, I noticed then when one of the terminals enters password for sudo, the other terminal has passwordless sudo access. This seems unusual/unsafe. Is it?

Comment: Remember that if anyone can access your sudo-enabled normal user, they'll eventually get sudo access also. For example by adding an alias for sudo that captures the password.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a configuration setting in the `sudoers` file. It's unusual because it's not the default, but not necessarily unsafe.

See `man sudoers`:

> `sudoers` uses per-user time stamp files for credential caching. […] By default, `sudoers` uses a separate record for each terminal, which means that a user's login sessions are authenticated separately. The `timestamp_type` option can be used to select the type of time stamp record `sudoers` will use.

and later,

> `sudoers` uses per-user time stamp files for credential caching. The `timestamp_type` option can be used to specify the type of time stamp record used. […]
>
> `global` A single time stamp record is used for all of a user's login sessions, regardless of the terminal or parent process ID. […]
> `ppid` A single time stamp record is used for all processes with the same parent process ID (usually the shell). […]
> `tty` One time stamp record is used for each terminal, which means that a user's login sessions are authenticated separately. […]
> `kernel` […]
>
> The default value is `tty`.

It seems likely that in your situation the value for `timestamp_type` has been changed from `tty` (or absent) to `global`. You can use `visudo` (or `sudo visudo` if you're not already root) to find the relevant line and comment it out.